# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): user.getSession is not a function

Tags: reactjs, aws-amplify

I am using **AWS amplify** in my app, I implemented a login function with google. But after login, i get this error `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): user.getSession is not a function` .

I have used Auth.federatedSignIn function for the login.

Here is my code:

```
       const responseGoogle = async (response) => {
    try {
      setLoading(true);
      const user = {
        name: response.profileObj.name,
        email: response.profileObj.email
      };

      const password = await Auth.forgotPassword(user.email);

      let expires_at = addMilliseconds(new Date(), 3600 * 1000).getTime();

      const result = await Auth.federatedSignIn(
        'google',
        { token: response.tokenId, expires_at },
        user
      );

      console.log(result);
      console.log('heree');

      history.push('/classes/google');
      setLoading(false);
      setUserInfo(loadedUsers, email);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      if (error.message !== `Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`) {
        enqueueSnackbar(error.message, { variant: 'error' });
      }
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };
```

The response is the response that I get from google.

does anyone know why I am getting this error? appreciated any type of help. Thanks

Comment: The user object does not have the function. Can you show us where you call this code and can you console.log the user right before you call it?

Comment: sure, i will edit me the question

Comment: the error occurs after 1minutes of login

Comment: user.getSession i an internal function called by aws amplify.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you have to check all restrictions auth is at the config json when you create auth function

The second thing is you have to pass three parameters in order to change passwords such as

- User
  Is the user session and you can get it by fetch the current sesion token and auth data.
- Oldpassword
- New Password